# How to detect from which app a user returned to your app?

Tags: android

A user presses on a URL in my app and the URL opens in the mobile browser.

**Is it possible that I detect in my app when a user returned from the mobile browser to my app?**

Many users will simply read the content of URL and press back to return to my app.

Test case:

1. user clicks on URL
2. mobile browser opens the URL
3. user touches BACK button
4. app detects that user came back to the app from the mobile browser

If I did not explain this well, please let me know.

Comment: how do you start the mobile browser? using `startActivity`?

Comment: @vmironov Sure. Via Intent.

Comment: then you can use `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`, as it's described in jimmithy's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you launch the URL with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Then, when the user returns to your application [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) will be called, and if the RequestCodes align you know it is the web browser.

For more information, take a look at this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Comment: You can decide on whatever code you want when you call startActivityForResult by setting it as the second argument. The RequestCodes are relative to your application.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'resultCode'. If a user presses the BACK, then it's CANCEL code???

Comment: It shouldn't matter for the case you mentioned above, but it will be RESULT_CANCELED by default.